# Creating a service to publish a post request based on user interval

Tags: python, fastapi

I need to create a service that will publish a task to a service based on user interval.
What is the optimal way to create a service that will be triggered based on user interval
For example:

```
def get_data(interval, request_no, total_duration):
    for i in range(total_duration):
        time.sleep(1)
        get_req = mongo.find_one({"_id": request_no})
        if get_req["status"] == "stop":
           break
        if i % interval == 0:
            requests.post(url)
```

This is an example code of my problem
how do i create this is as a service i can use fastAPI to create a backgroundTask but the problem is i have to check the database for everysecond is there any way or a service that will optimal to send the post request based on interval and status ? I can use any message broker or any other libraries but i never been exposed to these kind of problems.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to do, but if you're looking to perform some task every second, one way would be looking into the [repeated tasks feature in `fastapi-utils`](https://fastapi-utils.davidmontague.xyz/user-guide/repeated-tasks/).

Comment: I just wanted to know is there any way to check the status without checking the database every second